# How can I insert ad-hoc arguments in the middle of a variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
PROG := "prog -o1 one -o2 two --"
```

where nothing can come *after* `--`.  This is normally the calling pattern I want for `prog`:

```
thing:
    $(PROG) some files here
```

but there is a special target that I want to call as `prog -o1 one -o2 two -o3 three -- some other file`, so here's what I attempted to do (assuming `:=` set up the variable for lazy evaluation, though it seems I misunderstood the context there):

```
PROG := "prog -o1 one -o2 two $(OTHER_PROG_ARGS) --"

thing:
    $(PROG) some files here

other : OTHER_PROG_ARGS="-o3 three"
other:
    $(PROG) some other file
```

It seems that `PROG` is being expanded at assignment with `:=`; is there a way to do I want I want (e.g. with some kind of lazy expansion)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a more careful read of the manual, [specifically the difference between `:=` and `=`,](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors) I learned that `:=` assignments are expanded immediately while `=` is expanded recursively (for my purposes, 'lazily').

Assigning `PROG` with `=` and giving target-specific variables as before, the following works:

```
PROG = prog -o1 one -o2 two $(OTHER_PROG_ARGS) --

thing:
    $(PROG) some files here

other: OTHER_PROG_ARGS = -o3 three
other:
    $(PROG) some other file
```

Comment: You really, _really_ don't want to include quotes in your variables.  Make is not the shell: it doesn't parse any quotes.  They are simply treated like a normal character and passed to the shell, and that will break your command.

Comment: @MadScientist Nice catch, thanks :-) I've updated the answer to omit the quotation marks.